# Freezing at high temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science

> The temperature of the atmosphere at a high altitude is around 500° C. Yet an animal there would freeze to
> death and not boil. Explain.

I know that on the surface of the moon a pot of liquid will boil off because of very low atmospheric pressure. If by high altitude we assume the range of the thermosphere then the pressure at that height is also very small, so by the same logic shouldn't the animal boil there? I also tried using the Stefan Boltzmann law(SBL) on the animal and found that it will indeed heat up.

What is the correct explanation and what are the flaws in my reasoning?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Temperature is mean energy (entropy)  but to boil the animal requires a lot of total energy.   It's like the difference between a pot of hot water and a sheet of tin foil which is heated to 400 degrees (Fahrenheit).